# Firebase Security Rules - Two sets of rules for a .write cause one to work but not the other

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a set of security rules where in the `.write`, I have multiple rules where when I try them separately, they work fine, but when they are both together, one works, while the other fails.

I have a security rule that looks like this:

```
"user_feeds": {
     "$userId": {
        ".indexOn": ["timestamp"],
        ".read": "auth != null",  
         "$postId" : {
           ".write": "auth != null && (root.child('social').child('user_band_follows').child($userId).hasChild(newData.child('band_id').val()) || root.child('social').child('user_band_follows').child($userId).hasChild(data.child('band_id').val()))"
           }
         }
       }
```

in my `$postId` sub-tree, I'm trying to check to see if the parent has a node that corresponds to the `band_id` value of the data that is being inserted.

The data looks like:

```
{
   post_id: 1,
   band_id: '-L-tyesfsdf13434',
   timestamp: 34234234234
}
```

And an actual tree that these rules would correspond to look like:

```
{
   "user_feeds": {
     "userId1": {
        "-L-tyesfsdf13434": true
     }
   }
}
```

If you break the `.write` rule apart like so:

`(root.child('social').child('user_band_follows').child($userId).hasChild(newData.child('band_id').val()) || 
root.child('social').child('user_band_follows').child($userId).hasChild(data.child('band_id').val())`

^ This one works every time, no matter what

`root.child('social').child('user_band_follows').child($userId).hasChild(data.child('band_id').val())`

^ This one fails, unless it's by itself.

What is it about Firebase where a combination of rules like this could cause inconsistent success/failures? You would think that if both work on their own, they should work together as well?

Is there something I can do to ensure they both work correctly and allow the writes?

Comment: The rules you posted refer to child `user_band_follows`.  The "actual tree" you posted is `user_feeds`.  Are they related?

Comment: Hello again Bob! Yeah so `user_band_follows` refers to another tree that holds data for if a user follows a particular band